# Iterate ONLY first and second list python

Tags: python

I want to iterate a list but I want to iterate only first and second elements. For the edge case, if the list has only one or zero element, it should perform iterating one or zero time.

```
for element in a_list:
    print(element)
```

Use Case

- `a_list = [] -> ''`
- `a_list = ['a'] -> 'a'`
- `a_list = ['a', 'b'] -> 'ab'`
- `a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] -> 'ab'`
- `a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] -> 'ab'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for element in a_list[:2]:
    print(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output 2 elements then use:-

```
for element in a_list[:2]:
    print(element)
```

If you want to output 2 elements like a string just explained in the question use:-

```
"".join(a_list[:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Python 3 `print()` function you can avoid explicit iteration and get the output in one statement:

```
>>> a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> print(*a_list[:2], sep='')
ab
>>> a_list.pop()
>>> print(*a_list[:2], sep='')
ab
>>> a_list.pop()
>>> print(*a_list[:2], sep='')
ab
>>> a_list.pop()
>>> print(*a_list[:2], sep='')
a
>>> a_list.pop()
>>> print(*a_list[:2], sep='')
```

This slices `a_list`, unpacks the elements of the slice, and prints them using an empty string as the separator.

You can use the same function in Python 2 by adding this to the top of your script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which yields the first two elements.

```
def yield_two(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    yield next(it)
    yield next(it)
```

With usage:

```
for e in yield_two('abcde'):
    print(e) # 'a', 'b'
```